# Customize Togetherjs

Tags: togetherjs

Is it possible to customize togetherjs to make it look like part of the host app instead of an add-on. That would mean getting rid of the side toolbar completely and trigger the action from inside the host app. So for example, to invite someone instead of using the sidebar you would click some bottom on the host app that would perform the same action. Is this possible? If so, what is the level of effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is detailed documentation on how to do this:

https://togetherjs.com/docs/#configuring-togetherjs